# What is the difference between classical-quantum and completely classical states?

Tags: quantum-state, information-theory, cq-states

**States that are completly classical :**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\tilde\rho_{A B} & =\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} p_{X, Y}(x, y)(|x\rangle \otimes|y\rangle)(\langle x| \otimes\langle y|)_{A B} \\
& =\sum_{x \in \mathcal{X}} \sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} p_{X, Y}(x, y)|x\rangle\left\langle\left. x\right|_A \otimes \mid y\right\rangle\left\langle\left. y\right|_B\right. 
\end{aligned} \tag1
$$

- The states $\left\{|x\rangle_A\right\}_{x \in \mathcal{X}}$ and $\left\{|y\rangle_x\right\}_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}$ form an orthonormal basis for the respective systems $x$ and $y$.
- State has only classical correlations because can be prepared by LOCC.

**Classical-Quantum state :**
$$
\begin{aligned}
\rho^{A B} & =\sum_{x, y} p(x, y)|x\rangle\langle x| \otimes \pi_y \\
&\equiv \rho^{A B}=\sum_x p(x)|x\rangle\langle x| \otimes \rho_x^B
\end{aligned}
$$
with $p(x)=\sum_y p(x, y)$ and $\rho_x^B=\frac{1}{p(x)} \sum_y p(x, y) \pi_y$

Let the spectral decomposition of $\rho_x^B$ be:
$$
\rho_x^B=\sum_{y \in \mathcal{Y}} p_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) \left|y_x\right\rangle\left\langle\left. y_x\right|_B\right.
$$
where $\left\{\left|y_x\right\rangle\right\}$ forms orthonormal basis for $B$.

$$
\begin{aligned}
\Rightarrow \rho^{A B} & =\sum_x p_X(x)|x\rangle\left\langle  x\right|_A \otimes \sum_y p_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x) \mid y_x\rangle\left\langle y_x\right|_B \\
& =\sum_x \sum_y p_X(x) p_{Y \mid X}(y \mid x)|x\rangle\left\langle x\right|_A \otimes \mid y_x\rangle\left\langle y_x\right|_B
\end{aligned} 
$$
$$
=\sum_x \sum_y p_{X, Y}(x, y)|x\rangle\left\langle\left. x\right|_A \otimes \mid y_x\right\rangle\left\langle y_x\right|_B
\tag2
$$

**Question:** From equation 1 and 2, we see $\rho$ and $\tilde \rho$ have
similar form, expressed in terms of orhtonormal basis of both systems.
I would be greateful if someone properly explain (in detail) the
difference between Classical-Quantum states and States that are
completely classical, possibly in terms of the expresssions of $\rho$
and $\tilde \rho$.

Answer (score 2):

Your expressions give a pretty clear distinction: in the classical-quantum state, the eigenbases $\left|y_x\right>$ can be different for different states $x$ of the classical register $A$, and in the completely classical state the basis $\left|y\right>$ is fixed and does not depend on $x$.

We can also phrase it lake this: choose a basis $\{\left|y\right>\}_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}$ and say that classical states of the system $B$ are convex linear combinations of $\{\left|y\right>\left<y\right|\}_{y \in \mathcal{Y}}$ (so they are given by classical probability distributions on $\mathcal{Y}$).
Then a classical-quantum state has the form $$\rho^{AB} = \sum_{x} \left|x\right>\left<x\right| \otimes \rho_x^B$$ and it is completely classical exactly when all $\rho_x^B$ are classical states.